# Aspose Android via java

Tags: java, android, aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

I am using aspose java jar for web application and aspose Android via java for mobile application. By default aspose increase font size when i create pdf from mobile . Can someone tell me what exactly aspose doing for mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your inquiry. I suspect that the difference in font size is actually the difference in fonts. Android has a limited set of fonts and when Aspose.Words cannot find some fonts upon rendering document to PDF it tries to substitute them. You can configure font substitution rules using [FontSubstitutionSetings](https://apireference.aspose.com/java/words/com.aspose.words/FontSubstitutionSettings) class. 
If you need the exact rendering, then the same set of fonts must be used on different platforms. You can put the required fonts into a folder and use it as font source in [FontSettings](https://apireference.aspose.com/java/words/com.aspose.words/FontSettings).

Comment: Thnks i will try